# grep command is not search the complete pattern

Tags: shell

I am facing a problem while using the grep command in shell script. Actually I have one file (PCF_STARHUB_20130625_1) which contain below records.

```
SH_5.55916.00.00.100029_20130601_0001_NUC.csv.gz|438|3556691115
SH_5.55916.00.00.100029_20130601_0001_Summary.csv.gz|275|3919504621
SH_5.55916.00.00.100029_20130601_0001_UI.csv.gz|226|593316831
SH_5.55916.00.00.100029_20130601_0001_US.csv.gz|349|1700116234
SH_5.55916.00.00.100038_20130601_0001_NUC.csv.gz|368|3553014997
SH_5.55916.00.00.100038_20130601_0001_Summary.csv.gz|276|2625719449
SH_5.55916.00.00.100038_20130601_0001_UI.csv.gz|226|3825232121
SH_5.55916.00.00.100038_20130601_0001_US.csv.gz|199|2099616349
SH_5.75470.00.00.100015_20130601_0001_NUC.csv.gz|425|1627227450
```

And I have a pattern which is stored in one variable (INPUT_FILE_T), and want to search the pattern from the file (PCF_STARHUB_20130625_1). For that I have used below command

```
INPUT_FILE_T="SH?*???????????????US.*"
grep ${INPUT_FILE_T} PCF_STARHUB_20130625_1
```

The output of above command is coming as below

```
PCF_STARHUB_20130625_1:SH_5.55916.00.00.100029_20130601_0001_US.csv.gz|349|1700116234
```

I have two problem in the output, first is, only one entry is showing in output (It should contain two entries) and second problem is, output contains "PCF_STARHUB_20130625_1:" which should not be came. output should come like below

```
SH_5.55916.00.00.100029_20130601_0001_US.csv.gz|349|1700116234
SH_5.55916.00.00.100038_20130601_0001_US.csv.gz|199|2099616349
```

Is there any technique except grep please tell me.

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having copied your data in my `input.txt`:

```
$> (export INPUT_FILE_T="SH.*US\.*"; grep -h ${INPUT_FILE_T} input.txt)
SH_5.55916.00.00.100029_20130601_0001_US.csv.gz|349|1700116234
SH_5.55916.00.00.100038_20130601_0001_US.csv.gz|199|2099616349
```

**EDIT**

If you absolutely have to use the glob pattern, there may be a utility out there that does this, but I don't know it. The following quick C program will help:

```
#include <fnmatch.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 4096

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) { return EXIT_FAILURE; }

    FILE *in = stdin;
    const char *pattern = argv[1];

    char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH + 1];
    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_LENGTH, in))
    {
        if (!fnmatch(pattern, line, 0))
        {
            printf("%s", line);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To compile (the above program being in the file `myfnmatch.c`):

```
$> gcc -Wall myfnmatch.c -o myfnmatch
```

Exemple usage (note the redirect of `stdin` to `input.txt`):

```
(export INPUT_FILE_T="SH?*???????????????US.*"; ./myfnmatch ${INPUT_FILE_T} <./input.txt)
SH_5.55916.00.00.100029_20130601_0001_US.csv.gz|349|1700116234
SH_5.55916.00.00.100038_20130601_0001_US.csv.gz|199|2099616349
```

Comment: Thanks rectummelancolique for your response... but I can't the change the searching pattern(can't use `SH.*US\.*` instead of `SH?*???????????????US.*`)  as it is already feed on database.

Comment: In grep regexp `?` doesn't mean 'anything' (at least according to my `man grep`) it means `The preceding item is optional and matched at most once`. It seems your pattern is a `glob` pattern not a regexp. So you have to change it in order to work with grep.

Comment: If ?  doesn't any mean in grep expression then why it is searching one pattern, It would not search any pattern..

Comment: I'm just telling you like it is in my man. You are not telling us which shell you are using, whether your grep is GNU grep or a built-in of your shell, you are not giving us your full script either. Using your exact pattern does not return a single match for me. So I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Then you need to change your pattern to be a regex. I don't know why your grep matches anything in your file with your glob pattern. It shouldn't. What does `grep --version` say?

Comment: grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1

Copyright 1988, 1992-1999, 2000, 2001 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Comment: Something is not right. It should not match anything with your pattern. You must have something else elsewhere. In any case, either of my answer or Yossarian's is what you are looking for, you will never match what you want with your pattern.

Comment: You can check at your side with this pattern.. You may find same results as i got. by the way...please let me know If any other technique except grep by which we can find the pattern?

Comment: That's the first thing I did. It does not match anything with your data. See possible workaround if you have access to `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.*` to match any character any number of times, so your search pattern can be simplified (the last wildcard is also not needed):

```
INPUT_FILE_T="SH.*US\."
```

To remove the filename from the output, use the `-h` flag to grep:

```
$ grep -h ${INPUT_FILE_T} PCF_STARHUB_20130625_1
SH_5.55916.00.00.100029_20130601_0001_US.csv.gz|349|1700116234
SH_5.55916.00.00.100038_20130601_0001_US.csv.gz|199|2099616349
```

Comment: Thanks Yossarian for your response... but I can't the change the searching pattern(can't use SH.*US\.* instead of SH?*???????????????US.*) as it is already feed on database.

Comment: but problem is still coming, grep is not able to find the second pattern.